# How to AppendChild multiple times using C# and XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

AppendChild to add nodes to an XML file with C# and have hit a wall. I can't seem to add more than one node.

```
    private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int listCount = listView1.Items.Count;



    XmlDocument xmlDocNew = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocNew.Load(@"D:\test.xml");
    XmlNodeList ticketNodes = xmlDocNew.SelectNodes(@"//objects/ticket");
    int ticketCount = ticketNodes.Count;
    XmlElement mapElement = (XmlElement)xmlDocNew.SelectSingleNode(@"//objects[last()]");

    var newRec = xmlDocNew.CreateElement("ticket");
    newRec.SetAttribute("number", conBox.Text);
    mapElement.AppendChild(newRec);

    XmlNode node = xmlDocNew.SelectSingleNode(@"//objects/ticket[@number='" + conBox.Text + "']");


    XmlElement objectRec = xmlDocNew.CreateElement("object");
    newRec.AppendChild(objectRec);

    xmlDocNew.Save(@"D:/test.xml");

}
```

Even if I use newRec.AppendChild(objectRec) twice, or if I contain it in a for or foreach loop, I only end up with the following in my Xml.

```
<objects>
    <ticket>
        <object/>
    </ticket>
</objects>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to call CreateElement multiple times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    XmlElement objectRec = xmlDocNew.CreateElement("object");
    objectRec.InnerText = i.ToString();
    newRec.AppendChild(objectRec);
}
```

When you re-use the same element it is treated like a move. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks, I have already tried this and found it to work, however I don't know how many nodes I will need. It is based on a List View that is populated from an imported file. So how can I create a numbered objectRec for each item?

Comment: Edited the anser: just call the createElement inside a loop.

Comment: I was certain I had tried this before but obviously not as this works. Thanks for your help!